# Alexa Python Skill getting spoken value not slot id

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

My slot type has race track names in like Silverstone and Suzuka
They also have synonyms like Bristish and Japanese.

When I say British race I want the Python to return the value or id not the spoken words.

Currently I've got: `track = intent['slots']['trackSlot']['value']` which would return British, not the required Silverstone

Answer (score 1):

I've just used the Python to dig into the JSON as required.

```
track = intent['slots']['trackSlot']['resolutions']['resolutionsPerAuthority'][0]['values'][0]['value']['id']
```

Comment: It works. Just take into account that `trackSlot` is the name of the custom slot